For $X_t$ a continuous-time Markov chain, show $M_t := \frac{f(X_t)}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^t \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)$ is a martingale
Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a continuous-time Markov chain on finite state space $E$ with generator $G$ and let $f: E \to \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ be a function. Then I would like to show that
\begin{equation*}
M_t := \frac{f(X_t)}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^t \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)
\end{equation*}
is a unit-mean martingale wrt the natural filtration.
I have a strong suspicion that this result is related to this stackexchange problem, although I cannot seem to make my problem follow using a sneaky choice of function $f$ (replacing $f$ with $\log f$ is close I think?), nor can I seem to make a similar method carry over. How do I prove this result?
I also suspect that I have strong conditions on the problem and that it holds for any continuous Markov process and for some class of 'nice' functions $f$. An answer which does not specifically use finiteness of the state space or that $(X_t)$ is a CTMC would be much more satisfying to me!

A good place to look for this fact in a general context is the book Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence by Ethier and Kurtz; specifically, Lemma 3.2 on pages 174-175. They assume only that $\inf_Ef>0$.

@JohnDawkins Ah thanks very much! Am I right in (loosely) saying that they claim that this is a special case of the fact that, assuming the terms have finite mean, $X(t) \int_0^t Y(s) ds - \int_0^t X(s)Y(s) ds$ is a martingale for $X$ a martingale?

They argue, under minimal conditions ($f$, $g$ bounded and measurable, $f$ bounded below away from $0$), that if $f(X_t)-\int_0^t g(X_s),ds$ is a martingale, then so is your $M_t$, with the role of $Gf$ being taken by $g$.

A discussion later and I have an answer. Credit to Samuel Johnston. This answer seems to hold value as a more obscure (to me) method of proving a process exhibits the martingale property, so I hope this proves useful to someone else.
We refer to $G$ interchangeably as both an operator on functions,
\begin{equation*}
Gf(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0}\mathbb{E}_x\left[\frac{f(X_t) - f(X_0)}{t}\right]
\end{equation*}
and as a matrix
\begin{equation*}
G(x,y) := G\mathrm{\delta}_{y}(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}_x(X_t = y) - \mathbb{P}_x(X_0 = y)}{t}.
\end{equation*}
Write $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ for the natural filtration wrt $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$. The functions $f$, $1/f$ and $Gf$ are bounded so integrability is immediate. $M_t$ is also clearly $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable, so it remains to show that for all $x \in E$, $\mathbb{E}_x[M_{t+s}|\mathcal{F}_t] = M_t$.
Noting that $M_t$ is non-zero for all $t$, we see that it is equivalent to show that $\mathbb{E}_x\left[\frac{M_{t+s}}{M_t}\middle|\mathcal{F}_t\right] = 1$, or expanding this,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_x\left[\frac{f(X_{t+s})}{f(X_t)} \exp\left(-\int_{t}^{t+s}\frac{Gf(X_u)}{f(X_u)} \;du\right)\middle|\mathcal{F}_t\right] = 1
\end{equation*}
and by the Markov property, this is equivalent to showing that, for all $x \in E$ and for all $t \geq 0$
\begin{equation*}
r_x(t) := \mathbb{E}_x\left[\frac{f(X_{t})}{f(X_0)} \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{Gf(X_u)}{f(X_u)} \;du\right)\right] = 1
\end{equation*}
The method now is as follows: Find an ODE that $r_x$ satisfies, show that $r_x \equiv 1$ is a solution to the ODE and invoke uniqueness.
Let $A^{[a,b]}_k$ be the event that $k$ jumps occur in the interval $[a,b]$. Then as $h \downarrow 0$, we have that
\begin{align*}
r_x(t+h) &= \mathbb{E}_x\left[\left(\mathrm{1}_{A_0^{[0,h]}} + \mathrm{1}_{A_{1}^{[0,h]}} + \mathrm{1}_{A_{\geq 2}^{[0,h]}}\right)\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_0)} \exp\left(-\int_0^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right]
\end{align*}
Let us expand the brackets and look at each term individually. In particular, we use the property of a continuous Markov process that, for all $x,y \in E$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$ with $A \subset \{X_t = x\}$, then $\mathbb{E}[F((X_{t+s})_{s\geq 0})|A] = \mathbb{E}_{x}\left[F((X_s)_{s \geq 0})\right]$.
For no jumps, that means that $X_h = x$, so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{x}&\left[\mathrm{1}_{A_0^{[0,h]}}\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x\left[\mathrm{1}_{A_0^{[0,h]}}\exp\left(-h \frac{Gf(x)}{f(x)}\right)\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_h)}\exp\left(-\int_h^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right] \\
&= \left(1 -h \frac{Gf(x)}{f(x)} + o(h)\right)\mathbb{E}_x\left[\frac{f(X_{t})}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^{t} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right]\mathbb{P}_x\left(A_{0}^{[0,h]}\right)\\
&= \left(1 + h \left(-\frac{Gf(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{G(x,x)f(x)}{f(x)}\right)\right)r_x(t) + o(h)
\end{align*}
For one jump, we further condition on the state to which we jump. I.e.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{x}&\left[\mathrm{1}_{A_1^{[0,h]}}\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{x}\left[\sum_{y \neq x}\mathrm{1}_{A_1^{[0,h]}, X_h = y}\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_0)}\exp\left(-\int_0^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right] \\
&= \sum_{y \neq x}\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[\mathrm{1}_{A_1^{[0,h]}, X_h = y}\frac{f(X_{t+h})}{f(X_h)}\left(1 + o(1)\right)\exp\left(-\int_h^{t+h} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right] \\
&= \sum_{y \neq x}\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}\mathbb{E}_{y}\left[\frac{f(X_{t})}{f(X_0)}\left(1 + o(1)\right)\exp\left(-\int_0^{t} \frac{Gf(X_s)}{f(X_s)} \; ds\right)\right]\mathbb{P}_x(A_1^{[0,h]}, X_h = y) \\
&= \sum_{y \neq x}h\frac{G(x,y)f(y)}{f(x)}r_y(t) + o(h)
\end{align*}
And for at least 2 jumps, the corresponding term is $o(h)$. So putting it all together,
\begin{equation*}
r_x(t+h) = r_x(t) + h\left(\sum_{y \in E}\frac{G(x,y)f(y)}{f(x)}(r_y(t) - r_x(t))\right) + o(h) \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{equation*}
Now $r_x$ is certainly bounded over $x$ and $t$ so from the above equation, $r_x$ is right continuous and left continuous, hence continuous at $t$. $r_x(t)$ being right-differentiable is clear from the above equation as well, but for differentiability, we need also rewrite the above as
\begin{equation*}
r_x(t) = r_x(t-h) + h\left(\sum_{y \in E}\frac{G(x,y)f(y)}{f(x)}\left[(r_y(t) - r_x(t)) + (r_y(t-h) - r_y(t)) + (r_x(t-h) - r_x(t))\right]\right) + o(h)
\end{equation*}
and use continuity to say that $r_y(t-h) - r_y(t) = o(1)$ and $r_x(t-h) - r_x(t) = o(1)$, so that
\begin{equation*}
r_x(t-h) = r_x(t) - h\left(\sum_{y \in E}\frac{G(x,y)f(y)}{f(x)}(r_y(t) - r_x(t))\right) + o(h)
\end{equation*}
and $(\dagger)$ holds in the limit $h\to 0$, not just when $h \downarrow 0$. Hence,
\begin{equation*}
r_x'(t) = \left(\sum_{y \in E}\frac{G(x,y)f(y)}{f(x)}(r_y(t) - r_x(t))\right)
\end{equation*}
which defines a linear first-order ODE in $\mathbf{r}(t) := (r_x(t))_{x \in E}$. With the initial condition $\mathbf{r}(0) = 1$, the ODE must have a unique solution. But we note that $\mathbf{r}(t) \equiv 1$ is a solution to the ODE, thus is the unique solution. This completes the proof.
